# Is there a way to do a check if a command is run from a script or in the host directly?

Tags: powershell, if-statement, console, switch-statement

Afternoon and Happy Thanksgiving,

I have a logging function (that is part of a custom module) that uses the name of the script it's run from as the log file name. That all works fine, but if I wanted to use the logging function outside of a script, it errors out as it's creating a too long file name.

Is there a way to run a check so that if the function is called within a script it will use the script name, or if it's run direct in the console it either prompts for a name, or uses a default naming scheme.

Here's how I currently pull the script name from the function

```
(Get-ChildItem $MyInvocation.PSCommandPath | Select -Expand Name).Replace(".ps1",".log")
```

When run in a script

```
PS> .test.ps1
Write-Log "Hello World"
```

Outputs a log file named `test.log`

but if I run the same command direct to the console

```
Write-log "hello world"
```

you get the following error as it's collecting all the file names from the current directory

```
New-Item : The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260
characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.
```

Comment: Basically, the question is, how could you use a module's private function easily ? or if there is an easier way of doing it ? I'm having a hard time trying to understand what you want to accomplish

Comment: Are you going to modify the module directly? You should be able to check against `PSCommandPath` as it'll be populated if it's ran from within a script, and will be empty if ran by itself. Something like: `if ($MyInvocation.PSCommandPath) { 'script' } else { 'function' }`.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon what I'm trying to accomplish is, if my Write-Log function is called directly in the console (not from a script) have it use either a preset name, or prompt for a name to be entered.

By default it uses the above command to use the name of the script as the log name, and that's intended when it's used within a script. but I'd like if I use it outside of a script to default to a specific name, or prompt for one. I can sort out that aspect, just not a way to check if its being called from within a script or direct to the console

Comment: I think instead of trying to fix this problem you should update your `Write-Log` function to take a path to the log as argument

Comment: I have that in there currently as an option, it's more of a problem of convenience, if troubleshooting sections of a script, where you copy and paste it from script to console, you dont need to update the points, the function is called, with the -name parameter, it would just use a generic name of ``test`` as an example

Comment: @AbrahamZinala has already pointed you to the solution: if `$MyInvocation.PSCommandPath` has no value, the implication is that your function is being called from outside a script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you could do it this way, checking the [invocation's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.2#myinvocation) [`CommandOrigin`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.commandorigin?view=powershellsdk-7.2.0), if it's internal, return the [`$PSCommandPath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.2#pscommandpath) else, return the current location, in both cases changing the extension. I truly believe you should not go this route, your function should take a log path as argument.

```bash
function Write-Thing {
    # assume `CommandOrigin` is Runspace,
    # use current location if ran from host? your choice
    $Path = [IO.Path]::ChangeExtension($pwd.Path, 'log')

    # check if it's being called internally
    if($MyInvocation.CommandOrigin -eq 'Internal') {
        $Path = [IO.Path]::ChangeExtension($PSCommandPath, 'log')
    }

    # output the path for testing
    $Path
}

Write-Thing
```

Comment: I ended up borrowing bits of your answer and was able to accomplish what I was looking for. The biggest reason for my looking at this was I have some co-workers that run bits of code through ISE for their troubleshooting and I get feedback that my function doesn’t work, until I look at it and explain that it’s because they didn’t run the -start parameter first (which by design grabs the script name). But now it’ll generate a random file name just to capture the info during their ‘block’ testing